# get Locale sometimes return "en", sometimes return "en_US"

Tags: android

`val Locale = context.resources.configuration.locales.get(0).toString()`

`Log.i("locale" , Locale)` // this some times return 'en_US', sometimes return 'en'

I don't know what's difference with these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Locale object represents a specific geographical, political, or cultural region. An operation that requires a Locale to perform its task is called locale-sensitive and uses the Locale to tailor information for the user. For example, displaying a number is a locale-sensitive operation— the number should be formatted according to the customs and conventions of the user's native country, region, or culture.

"en" represents the language. You can find entire language codes [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry)

"US" represents the region. Region may not be known sometimes, so you may get "en" instead of "en_US" or "en_IN"...